# How to pass data to react components

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

My existing project is developed with Jquery. we decided to convert to React. I started working to convert to react. I developed some part and build that components and placed that build code in existing project. My question is how to pass the data or params from jquery part to React components?

Comment: jquery and react are based on javascript so the answer is simple use javascript :))

Comment: I need to pass the data when triggered the click event on jquery part

Comment: use some global variables

Comment: based on that value i need to make an ajax call. so i need to check the value is same or different. for that purpose i need to write an ajax call in componentWillReceiveProps right? for that purpose I need data through props

Comment: Is there any why to get the data through props?

Comment: what do you mean by "get the data through props"

Comment: I mean, is there any why to pass the data to react component through props. if possible i will get that data on every click event

Comment: okay, i will use window.variable, How to call the function when window variable having the new value?

Comment: what function you want to call?

Comment: every change i need to trigger an ajax call on react component based on the global variable value

Comment: so you want to do a ajax call with a react variable?

Comment: yes, based on the global variable change i need to make an ajax call on react component

Comment: why do you have a global variable, how is this variable changing, why aren't you triggering the ajax on the event that triggers the variable change?

Comment: can you provide some of your code?